# AS3 regex, retrieving as one value in OR group

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, regex-group

last night I decided to learn regex in order to create a "test" script parser and I've successfully done so in terms of variables :)

This is the AS3 regexp that I use to parse variables (not sure if this can be simplified but this is what came into my mind):

```
/\s*>(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:(?:"(.*?)")|>(\w+))\s*/gsm
```

The parsed variables take this format (example 1):

```
>ReferenceTestVariable = "Hello World"
```

or.. (example 2):

```
>TestVariable2 = >ReferenceTestVariable
```

The problem is with the groupings and I don't know how to word this properly but this is my regexp output for example 1 as an array

```
 [1]=ReferenceTestVariable, [2]=Hello World, [3]=
```

And this is the output for example 2:

```
 [1]=TestVariable2, [2]=, [3]=ReferenceTestVariable
```

How would I modify the group operator after the `=` to make it so index [2] and [3] are joined seeing as both index 2 and 3 are the values the variable stores? Also how would I modify the regexp to allow something like this:

```
>Test = "String", >Referencevariable, "Another String", "More strings", >Variable2
```

Comment: You can't combine groups from different alternatives. You just need to have your script check which one is non-null and use it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar I didn't know that. That is what I'm currently doing and I thought it would be possible to simplify it with the regexp itself. But how would I go about doing the last example if I wanted to store all values of `Test` into an array whether it stores a string or a reference?

Comment: Would you be OK with the quotes being in `index[2]` for example 1? That's the only way I can see to combine them.

Comment: BTW, it isn't necessary to include `\t` and `\n` in the character sets. `\s` includes all types of whitespace, including Tab and Newline.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks for the tip I'll keep it in mind and edit my regexp so it looks cleaner :) I guess having the quotes included would be alright since it'd allow me to differentiate between a string and a reference and maybe set a flag in the program itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
/\s*>(\w+)\s*=\s*(".*?"|>\w+)/gsm
```

`index[2]` will have quotes around it in case 1, or begin with `>` in case 2.

To do the second, it would be:

```
/\s*>(\w+)\s*=\s*((?:(?:".*?"|>\w+)\s*,\s*)*(?:".*?"|>\w+))/gsm
```

However, when you do this, all the comma-separated values will be together in `index[1]`.  Regular expression engines don't generally provide a way to get each of the values matched by a `*` or `+` separately.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?37u7n)

Comment: This should do it with  bit of simple string manipulation! Also any ideas or ways of doing the last bit would be a bonus! Thanks for your help Barmar :)